# Use of undeclared type 'KDDragAndDropManager' and 'KDDragAndDropCollectionViewDataSource'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've imported Cocoapod KDDragAndDropCollectionViews into app with Xcode 9, swift 4.

```
import KDDragAndDropCollectionViews
```

Am getting errors:

> Use of undeclared type 'KDDragAndDropCollectionViewDataSource'
>
> Use of undeclared type 'KDDragAndDropManager'

Tried

- cleaning proj with Product -> Clean, reopening Xcode, building proj
- uninstall the cocoapod then pod setup and pod install
- uninstall the cocoapod then pod cache clean --all and pod install

No luck fixing errors. A dozen other pods work fine. Any thoughts? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just downloading the whole project and dragging in just "KDDragAndDropCollectionView" and "KDDragAndDropManager" files into my project. Hope that helps!